# How to add CORS headers to several locations in nginx?

Tags: nginx, cors

I have been able to add a basic CORS support to my nginx server using the code provided in [enable-cors.org](http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html). However this solution implies to copy and paste that code in every location block, and I have several locations like the following:

```
location /game1 {
    alias   /development/games/game1/output;
    index  index.html;
}

location /game2 {
    alias   /development/games/game2/output;
    index  index.html;
}
```

Is there a way to create a rule that includes `add_header` outside the `location` blocks?

**Edit to clarify**: I've tried the following

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    charset UTF-8;

    #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

    if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        ...
    }
    location /game1 {
        alias /development/games/game1/output;
    }
    ...
}
```

But it does not work:

```
2015/10/14 19:00:01 [emerg] 3464#7384: "add_header" directive is not allowed
here in C:\development\servers\nginx-1.7.9/conf/nginx.conf:43
```

Comment: Putting it inside `location / {}` won't work?

Comment: @hjpotter92 That's the way it is working now, but doing C&P of the same 12 lines in every location seems... wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you can add `add_header` under the `server` block, but then it will *always* be sent, which might not be what you want.

Otherwise, you can create a file with the directives you want, and then `include` it from each `location` where you want the CORS headers added.

Comment: I had tried to put it under `server`, but I got an error... I will try the `include`approach, copying one line is clean enough for me